# C# Cannot find extension method for char struct

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Basically, I have this extension method written up:

```
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static bool IsMaths(this Char it)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(it) || char.IsControl(it)) { return true; }
        foreach (char each in new char[] { '-', '+', '(', ')', '/', '*', '%', '^', '.' })
        {
            if (each.Equals(it)) { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I try to call it:

```
else if (!Char.IsMaths(e.KeyChar)) { e.Handled = true; }
```

Visual Studio gives me the error that `'char' does not contain a definition for 'IsMaths'`. Why is this so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Visual Studio gives me the error that 'char' does not contain a
>   definition for 'IsMaths'. Why is this so?

Because an Extension Method works on an *instance of a type*, not the *type itself*. You're using static `char` methods, which is why it isn't possible.

You want to do:

```
else if (!e.KeyChar.IsMaths()) { e.Handled = true; }
```

Comment: The alternative, is to call the method like any other static method including the class name: `Extensions.IsMaths(e.KeyChar)`